# How to include the dynamically added row in datatable into DOM tree so that it behaves like any other row which was loaded on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, datatables

I am using datatable to represent  data in my application. I have a feature which clones any row on click of clone icon and dynamically adds the row below it.

The datatable has search feature which searches through all the rows present in the table, however it considers only the rows which were loaded in table while initial page load. It doesn't consider the newly dynamically added cloned rows.

What can be done so that the newly added rows are part of the table and are considered for searching like any other row.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rde0nbm/23/)

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  responsive: true,
  "search": {
    "regex": true,
    "smart": false
  },

  "scrollY": "400px",
  "scrollCollapse": true,
  "paging": false
});


$(document).on('click', '.cloneclick', function() {


  var index = $(this).parent().parent().index();

  var clonedElement=$(this).parent().parent().clone(true,true).html();

  clonedElement = "<tr>" + clonedElement + "</tr>";

  $('#example > tbody > tr').eq(index).after(clonedElement);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [**datatable's `row.add()` method**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()). It will automatically update the `data` in the datatable and refresh it.

And as you have the `row` so getting the data will be quite simple with [`row().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()):

This is how should be your code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cloneclick', function() {
  var clonedElement = table.row($(this).parent().parent()).data();
  table.row.add(clonedElement).draw();
});
```

This is [a working **diddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/1rde0nbm/26/).

Comment: It doesn't copy and align exactly as needed as my row is a bit custom https://jsfiddle.net/1rde0nbm/24/

Comment: @Chetan I updated [**your fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/1rde0nbm/26/), I misused the `row().data()`, now it works perfectly.